# swapping one number with two numbers in a list in python

Tags: python, swap

If I am given a list of numbers and I want to swap one of them with the next two numbers.
Is there a way to do this in one shot, without swapping the first number twice?

To be more specific, let's say I have the following swap function:

```
def swap_number(list, index):
    '''Swap a number at the given index with the number that follows it.
Precondition: the position of the number being asked to swap cannot be the last
or the second last'''

    if index != ((len(list) - 2) and (len(list) - 1)):
        temp = list[index]
        list[index] = list[index+1]
        list[index+1] = temp
```

Now, how do I use this function to swap a number with the next two numbers, without calling swap on the number twice.

For example: I have the following list: `list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Now, how do I swap 3 with the 4 and 5 in one shot?

The expected output would be

list = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Can you give us a) examples of input and expected output, and b) your own attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def swap(lis, ind):
    lis.insert(ind+2, lis.pop(ind)) #in-place operation, returns `None`
    return lis
>>> lis = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lis = swap(lis, 3)
>>> lis
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But is there a way to use my swap function to do this?

Comment: @VrishtiDutta I've updated my solution to use a function this time.